# How can I change cull mode in tilemap occluder in godot4?

Tags: godot

I need to see one tile and nothing behind it. If I use usual light occluder I can change cull mode and its what I need, but in tilemap I cant find this.

I tried turn on/off tile occluder. It works but its not what I need